# didSelectRowAt is not working with my UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having trouble with my UITableVieController. It is not correctly calling my didSelectRowAt function. I have multiple sections in my UITableView but another section of my code with the same exact code is working perfectly fine and I can not figure out why this is not working

I have already checked if my table view has the correct delegate and data source and it does.

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? 1 : songList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell", for: indexPath) as! InfoCell

            cell.playlistImage.image = playlistImage
            cell.name.text = selectedPlaylist
            cell.nuberOfSongs.text = "Number of Songs: \(playlistCount)"

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongCell", for: indexPath) as! SongCell
            cell.SongTitle.text = songList[indexPath.row]
            cell.SongArtist.text = artistList[indexPath.row]
            cell.SongImage.image = imageList[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.section != 0 {

            selectedItem = mediaList[indexPath.row]

            play(selectedItem: selectedItem)

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPlayer", sender: self)

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

This is all of my code for creating the sections and the rows that go in those sections. It also contains the code for didSelectRowAt but that function is not being called at all.

Comment: the only reason that it won't do anything is because you are always selecting a row on section 0

Comment: @MXNMike why am I always selecting a row at section 0?

Comment: Either the `delegate` isn't really set or there are views on the cell preventing the taps from resulting in the row being selected.

Comment: Thats the only reason why it should do anything if you say that the delegates are properly set, if you put a breakpoint in the line of your check, do you hit that breakpoint?

Comment: “but that function is not being called at all“ how do you know?

Comment: @matt I know because it is not performing the segue or playing the music when I click on the cell. I also had a print statement in that section and nothing is printed when I click on a cell.

Comment: But did you try putting a breakpoint on the very first statement in the function? The `if`. Not performing the segue does not mean the function was not called!

Comment: @MXNMike I added a breakpoint and it does not hit that breakpoint. I also removed the check and added a breakpoint and that is not hit eaither.

Comment: What do you do that would select it?

Comment: @DevAlphas try the view debugger and check if you are able to select the cell, that nothing is blocking it, even check if it’s user interact-able

Comment: @DevAlphas can you ensure the `allowsSelection` property of your tableView is `true`? (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614911-allowsselection)

Comment: Add `tableView.allowsSelection = true` in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing a `UITapGestureRecogniser` to your superview of the UITableView, if this is the case then the `didSelectRowAt` method of UITableview won't work because your superview is receiving the touch instead of tableview cell.

For this, you can add a delegate to your `UITapGestureRecogniser` like this :

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectorFunction))
tap.delegate = self
superview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

After this just conform your viewcontroller to this delegate

```
extension YourViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if (touch.view?.isDescendant(of: yourTableView))!
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```